# Array.push, array stays empty

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, redis

I'm trying to get all hget values out of my redis db. But the array logs stays empty. Could you guys please take a look into it? Thanks

```
getAllHMSets = (cb) ->
  client.keys "log:*", (err, logKeys) ->
    if not err and logKeys isnt null
      logs = new Array()
      i = 0
      while i < logKeys.length
        client.hgetall logKeys[i], (err, log) ->
          if not err and log isnt null
            logs.push log
        i++

      if logs.length is logKeys.length
        cb logs  if typeof cb is "function"
```

Comment: Could it be that hgetall is executed asynchronously (that would explain the use of a callback)?

Comment: Thanks, Thilo. HGETALL is async, I'm using redis.multi() now which solves the issue ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think there are 2 problems with your code:

1. you should write it in more idiomatic CoffeeScript
2. your call to hgetall must also use a callback eitherwise your array will never be filled.

```
getAllHMSets = (cb) ->
  client.keys "log:*", (err, logKeys) ->
    if not err and logKeys isnt null

      logs = []

      for value in logKeys
        client.hgetall logKeys[i], (err, log) ->
          if not err and log isnt null
            logs.push log
            if logs.length is logKeys.length
              cb logs  if typeof cb is "function"
```

Comment: either your indentation is busted or you miss a return

Comment: oops! where do I miss a return?

Comment: `if not err and logKeys isnt null`

Comment: sorry, I dont get it. Why would there be a return missing?
What should a return at this position do?

Comment: your if here is basically useless since you don't have anything in it. Actually coffee will refuse to parse it since it's not a post if (there's nothing before) and it has no block

Comment: ok. now I got it. yeah your right. and probably it would generate syntax error. thanks. I will change it